# Ember-data 1.0.0-beta.19: store.find() returns DS.INTERNALMODEL instances

Tags: ember-data

I have update Ember-data to 1.0.0-beta.19 and now `store.find('events')` resolved promise returns `DS.INTERNALMODEL` instances, instead of `DS.MODEL`. With Ember-data 1.0.0-beta.18 it was working fine. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

At the end i found out that somewhere in my app code i was using Ember-data internal code like `store.find('events.content')`, causing an exception. The debugger was not so helpful tracing it, but removing this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug, if the promise resolves with DS.InternalModel, those are only for internal use of Ember-Data and shouldn't be exposed to user code. Please file a bug if this is still a problem

Answer (score 0):

This is on purpose. It's noted in the chanelog:

- [#3094](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/3094) Lazily materialize DS.Models for app code, use InternalModel inside ED otherwise

It should work largely with no issues. Are you having issues with it?

You can access the `DS.Model` using `InternalModel.record`

Comment: Yes, calling `get` function on internal models i'm getting an undefined function error.

Comment: You can access the `DS.Model` using `InternalModel.record`

Comment: is this a breaking change?? cause it didn't mentioned on Breaking Changes section. It seems that i have to made changes in a lot of parts in my app...

Comment: so now i have to do `store.find('events').then(function(events){ events.get('content')[0].record.get('id') });` in order to get a record id??

Comment: You should be able to do `store.find(function(events) {.events.objectAt(0).id; });`

Comment: and how i iterate with `{{#each}}` method in templates? should i use `InternalModel.record.id`?

Comment: Really there should be no change when using a template.. `{{#each models as |model|}} {{model.id}} {{/each}}`

Comment: Ok i'll check it out more.. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: This doesn't work: `store.find('events').then(function(events){events.filter(function(event, index, self) {
  if (event.get('starts_now')) { return true; }
})})` TypeError: event.get is not a function. I can't call getter function on returned records?

Comment: Does `event.starts_now` work? I believe you don't need to use `get` with `InternalModel`s

Comment: but i'm really confused with InternalModels. isn't only for ember-data code internal use? is this a breaking change??

Comment: What you're trying to do works for me.. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sowafa/1/edit?js,output